# xperia z5 broken screen locked need data

Tags: adb, usb-debugging, sony-xperia, locked-out, broken-screen

I had a sony xperia z5 compact for about 2 weeks until i smashed the screen. I have searched online to find some help to recover my photos and videos taken with the device. I didnt have any cloud set up so i cant get them from there. OTG cable has to be turned on EVERY TIME from the settings on the Z5, it seems the Z3 was plug and play good to go OTG, but not the Z5.
The screen is unresponsive and barely visible and it has a passcode lock (as fingerprint function is locked, and wont reset after a soft reset). I have until the end of the week to return the phone to my carrier and would like to get the data from it before i send it back. I have no knowledge of scripting ADB or how i can activate usb debugging with a damaged screen.
Is there a script i can download as a zip and paste to the root of an external SD card which can transfer or duplicate the files from the internal to external storage? or a zip that can activate usb debugging?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off the phone with power button and volume+ (hold them together), connect the mouse or keyboard with OTG cable and than turn on the phone. Then you can use the mouse to do everything.