# get files from sony z5 compact with broken screen

Tags: usb-debugging, file-transfer, broken-screen

So I run into this problem with my phone: I am trying to get my pictures from the phone after my screen broke. So I already did some research on my own, but now I am stuck. I figured out the following:

1. Making the USB OTG work in combination with a mouse to regain control over my phone again. I used [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/132041/xperia-z5-broken-screen-locked-need-data) topic on android stackexchange
2. I enabled usb debugging in developer mode.

So now I thought that I would be able to simply connect my phone to my computer, using Windows 10, and that I would have access to all of my files. The idea came from [this](http://joyofandroid.com/cracked-or-broken-android-screen-recover-photos/) site. But unfortunately, I can still see no files what so ever.

Can anybody please help me out? If it helps, I also have Linux mint available.

Best,
Koen

Answer (score 0):

Easiest to solve with Linux, as you have USB debugging enabled¹.

1. Get the ADB tools running on your Linux computer. Should be as easy as `sudo apt install android-tools-adb`²
2. Connect your Android device via USB
3. On the Linux machine, check whether the device was detected by entering `adb devices`. If it's not listed, our ADB tag wiki² again has some hints
4. now you can use `adb pull` to get content from your Android device to your Linux machine

Of course, finding the content is another issue. For that, there are several graphical managers available – in case you don't feel comfortable with „plain shell commands“ executed via `adb shell`. For those, be welcome to check with [the corresponding list on my own site](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_adb#group_947). I personally use [adbfs-rootless](https://github.com/spion/adbfs-rootless) to mount the storage via ADB, so I can use any file manager for the job.

Also worth a look: our [broken-screen](/questions/tagged/broken-screen) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info)

---

¹ <sub>though the same can be achieved on Windows, there you'd have to install a bunch of drivers to get it working</sub>
² <sub>for alternatives and additional details, please see our [adb tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info)</sub>